# Find global minimum for discrete function

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, numpy, scipy

This is what my code looks like when simplified:

```
# This function returns some value depending on the index (integer)
# with which it is called.
def funct(index):
    value <-- some_process[index]
    # Return value for this index.
    return value
```

where the indexes allowed are stored in a list:

```
# List if indexes.
x = [0,1,2,3,...,1000]
```

I need to find the `x` index that returns the *minimum* value for `funct`. I could just apply a brute force approach and loop through the full `x` list storing all values in new a list and then simply find the minimum with `np.argmin()`:

```
list_of_values = []
for indx in x:
    f_x = funct(x)
    list_of_values.append(f_x)

min_value = np.argmin(list_of_values)
```

I've tried this and it works, but it becomes quite expensive when `x` has too many elements. I'm looking for a way to optimize this process.

I know that [scipy.optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) has some optimization functions to find a global minimum like [anneal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.anneal.html#scipy.optimize.anneal) and [basin-hopping](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html#scipy.optimize.basinhopping) but I've failed to correctly apply them to my code.

Can these optimization tools be used when I can only call a function with an integer (the index) or do they require the function to be continuous?

Comment: Optimization algorithms generally require assumptions about the function: uniqueness of mimina and smoothness for example. You don't give any of these.  NB: making a list just to find its minimum is silly.  @mgilson gave one way to avoid this.  You can also use a loop, keeping track of the current minimum, updating it when a new one is found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the python builtin `min` accepts a `key` function:

```
min_idx = min(x, key=funct)
min_val = funct(min_idx)
```

This gives you an O(n) solution implemented about as well as you're going to get in python.

Comment: So that means I can not use the methods defined in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html?

Comment: @Gabriel: how should that work? Only if your function has some structure to exploit (e.g. convexity), you can do better than linear time.

Comment: You need to know something about your mathematical function to apply those methods appropriately. Without knowing the properties of the function you may get nonsensical results. Also, those methods will give you a point in your domain which minimizes the functional, not the index into your array. E.g. the minimizer of (x+1)^2 is at x = -1 which is not a valid index

Comment: @Gabriel -- you probably *can*, but i doubt that you would really gain a whole lot of performance out of it.  Of course, all of those algorithms likely make assumptions about the function that you're putting in (smoothness, differentiability).  If you know that you meet some of those constraints, you *might* see a benefit in switching, but I'm skeptical.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, I understand a bit better the issue now.